# There is no active transaction error while installing OroCommerce App

Tags: mysql, orocommerce, php-8.1

I'm trying to install OroCommerce application, but i'm getting this error

```
  [PDOException]                  
  There is no active transaction
```

I'm using the below command to install

```
php bin/console oro:install --timeout=2000 -vvv
```

I'm using Mysql 8.0 and PHP 8.1

[image]

Anyone can help here ?

Comment: This seems to be a random failure. Usually to fix this issue you have to clear the database and the application cache and start over.

Comment: I changed to PostgreSQL, it works fine